# PHP: send request post login

Tags: php

I would like to extract some data from a web page aspx, but I get the following message:

```
1|#||4|29|pageRedirect||%2ferrors%2fGenericError.aspx|
```

I analyzed the post request from firefox and obtained the following post parameters:

```
    "headersSize": 1240,
      "postData": {
        "mimeType": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "params": [
          {
            "name": "ctl00$ctl00$ScriptManager",
            "value": "ctl00$ctl00$ScriptManager|ctl00$ctl00$mainContent$titleContent$btnFiltro"
          },
          {
            "name": "__EVENTTARGET",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "name": "__EVENTARGUMENT",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "name": "__VIEWSTATE",
            "value": "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"
          },
          {
            "name": "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR",
            "value": "97C62ED9"
          },
          {
            "name": "__EVENTVALIDATION",
            "value": "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"
          },
          {
            "name": "ctl00$ctl00$hwsid",
            "value": "4f1737ba-1f50-4c8e-bd38-2b3fcf2adbe0"
          },
          {
            "name": "ctl00$ctl00$PageSessionId",
            "value": "99b33af9-74e2-4c01-ac20-163a7fc5ed0d"
          },
          {
            "name": "ctl00$ctl00$DefaultUrl",
            "value": "/Default.aspx"
          },
          {
            "name": "ctl00$ctl00$GenericErrorUrl",
            "value": "../../errors/GenericError.aspx"
          },
          {
            "name": "ctl00$ctl00$PopupElement",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "name": "ctl00$ctl00$PollingTimeoutSecs",
            "value": "60"
          },
          {
            "name": "ctl00$ctl00$mainContent$titleContent$cldDataInizio$txtData",
            "value": "26/08/2018"
          },
          {
            "name": "ctl00$ctl00$mainContent$titleContent$cldDataFine$txtData",
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "name": "ctl00$ctl00$mainContent$titleContent$dropStatiRichiesta",
            "value": "4"
          },
          {
            "name": "ctl00$ctl00$mainContent$titleContent$dropTipiRichiesta",
            "value": "-1"
          },
          {
            "name": "__ASYNCPOST",
            "value": "true"
          },
          {
            "name": "ctl00$ctl00$mainContent$titleContent$btnFiltro",
            "value": "Filtra"
          }
        ]
```

so I made the following code in php:

```
$postdata_ini_r = 
array(
    'ctl00$ctl00$ScriptManager' => 'ctl00$ctl00$ScriptManager|ctl00$ctl00$mainContent$titleContent$btnFiltro',
    'ctl00$ctl00$hwsid' => $hwsid_ini,
    'ctl00$ctl00$PageSessionId' => $pagesessionid_ini,
    'ctl00$ctl00$DefaultUrl' => $defaulturl_ini,
    'ctl00$ctl00$GenericErrorUrl' => $genericerrorurl_ini,
    'ctl00$ctl00$PopupElement' => '',
    'ctl00$ctl00$PollingTimeoutSecs' => $pollingtimeoutsecs_ini,
    'ctl00$ctl00$mainContent$titleContent$cldDataInizio$txtData' => $oggi,
    'ctl00$ctl00$mainContent$titleContent$cldDataFine$txtData' => '',
    'ctl00$ctl00$mainContent$titleContent$dropStatiRichiesta' => '4',
    'ctl00$ctl00$mainContent$titleContent$dropTipiRichiesta' => '1',
    '__EVENTTARGET' => '',
    '__EVENTARGUMENT' => '',
    '__VIEWSTATE' => $viewstate_ini,
    '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR' => $viewstategenerator_ini,
    '__EVENTVALIDATION' => $eventvalidation_ini,    
    '__ASYNCPOST' => 'true',
    'ctl00$ctl00$mainContent$titleContent$btnFiltro' => 'Filtra'     
 );
 $campo_r = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($campo_r , CURLOPT_URL, $richieste_c); 
curl_setopt($campo_r , CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($campo_r , CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postdata_ini_r)); 
curl_setopt($campo_r , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($campo_r , CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0");
curl_setopt($campo_r , CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($campo_r , CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($campo_r , CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt($campo_r , CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt($campo_r , CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cook_aut);
$html_ini_r = curl_exec($campo_r ); 
curl_close($campo_r ); 


$htm1_R= htmlentities($html_ini_r);

echo $htm1_R;
```

Where am I wrong? Cookies are correct, because in other web pages I can download data, the link is correct, I don't know where I am wrong.
All the variables are correct, I have already checked the accuracy of the values.

Comment: are you get values by ```$_POST[]``` in the server side?

Comment: I don't manage the server, so I don't know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by simply deleting parameters from  **$postdata_ini_r**:

```
$postdata_ini_r = 
array(
    '__VIEWSTATE' => $viewstate_ini_r,
    '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR' => $viewstategenerator_ini_r,
    '__EVENTVALIDATION' => $eventvalidation_ini_r,
    'ctl00$ctl00$hwsid' => $hwsid_ini_r,
    'ctl00$ctl00$PageSessionId' => $pagesessionid_ini_r,
    'ctl00$ctl00$DefaultUrl' => $defaulturl_ini_r,
    'ctl00$ctl00$GenericErrorUrl' => $genericerrorurl_ini_r,
    'ctl00$ctl00$PopupElement' => '',
    'ctl00$ctl00$PollingTimeoutSecs' => $pollingtimeoutsecs_ini_r,
    'ctl00$ctl00$mainContent$titleContent$cldDataInizio$txtData' => $oggi,
    'ctl00$ctl00$mainContent$titleContent$cldDataFine$txtData' => '',
    'ctl00$ctl00$mainContent$titleContent$dropStatiRichiesta' => '-1', 
    'ctl00$ctl00$mainContent$titleContent$dropTipiRichiesta' => '-1', 
    'ctl00$ctl00$mainContent$titleContent$btnFiltro' => 'Filtra'    
);
```

Thanks to all!